# How to call a method with List<Child>, but method's parameter is List<Parent>?

Tags: java, inheritance, parent, extends

I am having some problem, and I can't understand why it isn't working.
I have a Parent class:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    ...
}
```

and 2 Child classes:

```
public class Child1 extends Parent {
    ...
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {
    ...
}
```

I have a method, which is working with the children list. But it should work with both type Child1 and Child2, so I thought it should work:

```
public static void doSomething(List<Parent> list) {
    ...
}
```

and this is how I call it:

```
List<Child1> children = dao.getChildren("1");
doSomething(children);

List<Child2> children2 = dao.getChildren("2");
doSomething(children2);
```

But it doesn't work, it shows this error:

```
The method doSomething(List<Parent>) in the type MyClass is not applicable for the arguments (List<Child1>)
The method doSomething(List<Parent>) in the type MyClass is not applicable for the arguments (List<Child2>)
```

How could I write this code?

Comment: what does doSomething() return? Your code doesn't show a return type

Comment: I updated, I am sorry, but it doesn't matter what that method does

Comment: Ah, I read the question too quickly, thought you were doing List<Child1> children = doSomething(chidren). Kinda silly in hindsight :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh I did it! This code is working for the doSomething method:

```
public static void doSomething(List<? extends Parent> list) {
    ...
}
```